# Add Custom UISlider to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, addsubview

I have made a custom `UISlider` class (`CustomSlider`) that I would simply like to add as a subview to my UIView. So, I do this:

```
var slider = CustomSlider()
self.view.addSubview(slider)
```

The `UISlider` is being added to the `UIView`, but it is the default slider, not my custom one. Why is this happening? I've looked all over the internet and cannot find a solution.

Comment: It would help if you showed some details about your `CustomSlider` class.

Comment: @rmaddy It's just a UISlider class that changes the slider's thumb image, tint, etc.

Comment: I mean [edit] your question and show the `CustomSlider` class declaration and at least its `init` methods.